# Есть разница при вызове interrupt() в состоянии ожидания под sleep() и под wait()?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Существует ли разница в поведении потока при вызове у него метода `interrupt()`, в случаях когда он остановлен методоми `sleep()` и когда `wait()`? Или просто флаг `isInterrupted()` меняется и все?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь нет, но в обоих случаях будет не просто установлен флаг, работа методов прервется с выбрасыванием `InterruptedException`